# How to adding Spring Security logout to system to logout users?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

How to adding Spring Security logout to system to logout users?  I am trying the following but it does not work:

```
<http use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url access="hasRole('ROLE_VERIFIED_MEMBER')" pattern="/ask-question**" />
         <intercept-url pattern='/*' access='permitAll' />

        <form-login default-target-url="/ask" />

        <logout logout-success-url="/" />

        <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/login?logout_successful=1" />

        <session-management session-fixation-protection="newSession">
            <concurrency-control max-sessions="1"/>
        </session-management>

    </http>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to remove one of the `<logout/>` tags. Then, when you want to logout just navigate to `/j_spring_security_logout`. And if it's not working again, you should tell us what exactly is not working.

Answer (score 0):

With two `<logout>` elements, I expect Spring is simply ignoring the second, which is the one wherein the `logout-url` property is specified. Remove or comment out the first one, and try again, or add the `logout-url` property to the first one (and remove or comment out the second), and see what happens.

Comment: In fact, I tested this, and that is exactly what is happening. The first one listed takes precedence, and it doesn't have a `logout-url` property specified.